# Iterating over array with bluebird promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to iterate over an array with promises by first multiplying all values in an array by 2 THEN returning the updated array:

```
var Bluebird = Promise.noConflict()
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function loopThroughArray(arr) {
  return Bluebird.each(arr, function(value) {
    return value = value * 2;
  }).then(function(arr) {
    console.log('--done--');
    console.log(arr);
    // should return [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18];
  });
}

loopThroughArray(arr);
```

However, my function is still returning the original array.. can someone help? Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mpo4yrmu/71/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: perhaps you want to `.map` to map to a new array of values- [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/mpo4yrmu/72/) (can't see the point of using promises for this!)

Comment: There's no point in using promises when nothing in your code is asynchronous?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `.each` use `.map`.

`.each` doesn't bother about the return value, `.map` **does**.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/free_soul/mpo4yrmu/73/

```
var Bluebird = Promise.noConflict()
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function loopThroughArray(arr) {
  return Bluebird.map(arr, function(value) {
    return value = value * 2;
  }).then(function(arr) {
    console.log('--done--');
    console.log(arr);
    // does return [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 18, 19];
  });
}

loopThroughArray(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var Bluebird = Promise.noConflict()
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function loopThroughArray(arr) {
    return Bluebird.map(arr, function(value) {
    return value = value * 2;
  }).then(function(arr) {
    console.log('--done--');
    console.log(arr);
    // should return [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 18, 19];
  });
}

loopThroughArray(arr);
```

Use `.map` to achieve your goal as I shown here.

Why `.each` will not work here?

Answer: `each` function is an iterator. It will iterate over an array or array of promises, where `map` will also iterate over array but it will wait for the value returning from it's body and store that return value of each iteration into array.

That array you can get in next then block.

Answer (score 0):

`Bluebird.each()` resolves to the original array unmodified, which is why you are logging the original array.

Bluebird.each

> ...Resolves to the original array unmodified, this method is meant to be used for side effects. If the iterator function returns a promise or a thenable, then the result of the promise is awaited, before continuing with next iteration.

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html

The correct method would be to use *Javascript's native `Array.prototype.map()`*:

```
//your promise code here
...function(arr) {
    console.log('done!');
    console.log(arr.map(function(element) {
      return element * 2;
    }));
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

the `value` you are getting is not a reference value. you can do it something like this but the array values will be changed.

```
var Bluebird = Promise.noConflict()
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function loopThroughArray(arr) {
     Bluebird.each(arr, function(value, i) {
     arr[i] = arr[i] * 2;
  }).then(function(arr) {
    console.log('--done--');
    console.log(arr);
    // should return [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 18, 19];
  });
}

loopThroughArray(arr);
```